# Android bubble sort not working

Tags: java, android, bubble-sort

I am new to android programming and I tried to do bubble sort by inputting numbers in one EditText and the sorted numbers will be outputted on the second EditText. The program has stopped unexpectedly once I click the Sort button. Please tell me what's wrong.

```
package com.example.sorting;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

EditText enterNum;
EditText sortedNum;
Button sortNow;

int num[] = new int[5];
int i, n, j;
int temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enterNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterNum);
    sortedNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sortedNum);
    sortNow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortNow);
    sortNow.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View  v){ 
            BubbleSort();}});

}


public void BubbleSort(){

    Spannable spn=enterNum.getText();
    num[5]=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());

            for (i=0;i<5;i++){
                for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
                    if(num[i]>num[j]){
                        temp = num[i];
                        num[i] = num[j];
                        num[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }


    sortedNum.setText(String.valueOf(num[0])+String.valueOf(num[1])+String.valueOf(num[2])+String.valueOf(num[3])+String.valueOf(num[4]));


}
```

}

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: What do you mean by "Stopped unexpectedly"? An exception? If yes, which one and on which line? You need to be more precise, we won't debug this for you without a trace.

Comment: here's from the logcat:
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at com.example.sorting.MainActivity.BubbleSort(MainActivity.java:39)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at com.example.sorting.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)

Comment: 04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: 04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 08:20:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line should give you ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:

```
num[5]=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());
```

Because you have declared,

```
int num[] = new int[5];
```

So your array has five elements with indexes 0,1,2,3,4
Highest index is **4**

**Change it to**

```
num[4]=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());
```

Also change 5 to 4 in the following loops,

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){ 
                for(j=i+1;j<4;j++){
```

**Suggestion**: It is good to use num.length, instead of using absolute values such as 4 and 5

**EDIT:**

```
public void BubbleSort() {

    Spannable spn = enterNum.getText();
    for (int i = 0; i < spn.length(); i++){
        num[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+spn.charAt(i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) {
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < spn.length(); i++){
        result += num[i];
    }
    sortedNum.setText(result);

}
```

Comment: thank you so much I never expected to have an answer this fast. I will let u know if it works... :)

Comment: yeah it works without the exception error! but this time the output is still unsorted. thank you so much!

Comment: The parsing of input numbers was not correct `num[5]=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());`, fixed and edited

Comment: I see. I have much to learn. Thank you so much @payeli. Its like I am speaking to a god. I will not stop learning programming in return of your kindness.